# How to compare nullable variable in linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I try to select some data by linq but system shows me this error

> Expression of type 'System.DateTime' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Object' of method 'Boolean Equals(System.Object)'

My WorkingResults.EffectiveDate is DateTime? but my date variable is DateTime. How do I  change my code to fix this out?

```
  WorkingResult workingResultObj = (from workingResult in this.DataWorkspace.ApplicationData.WorkingResults
where workingResult.EmployeeCode == employeeCode  && workingResult.EffectiveDate.Equals(date)                                         
select workingResult).FirstOrDefault();
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.HasValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094.aspx) and Its must like

```
...
where workingResult.EmployeeCode == employeeCode && 
(workingResult.EffectiveDate.HasValue && 
 workingResult.EffectiveDate.Value.Date == date.Date).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, there are a couple of workarounds.  First, you could make it a DateTime:

```
workingResult.EffectiveDate.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.MinValue).Equals(date)
```

I don't know what a valid date is.  Or, you could use Object.Equals:

```
Object.Equals(workingResult.EffectiveDate, date)
```

Which may not give you the intended results. If you always know effective date has a value, then you can use @spajce approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
 WorkingResult workingResultObj = 
  (
      from workingResult 
      in this.DataWorkspace.ApplicationData.WorkingResults
      where 
            workingResult.EffectiveDate.HasValue
            && workingResult.EmployeeCode == employeeCode  
            && workingResult.EffectiveDate.Value == date                                         
      select workingResult
  ).FirstOrDefault();
```